# Compute rate of change from subset rows tagged by condition to the rest of the rows below the tagged one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```python
import pandas as pd

data = {'score':  [1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29, 37, 46],
        'tag': [False, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, True, False]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['score', 'tag'])
```

that I need to calculate the rate of change `(x - y)/y` in `score` between each row and its `latest` row that's tagged `True` (not including the tagged row itself).

With the previous example, the desired output shall be:

```python
>>> df
   score    tag   rate
0      1  False    NaN  # NaN as no row was tagged True before
1      2   True    NaN  # NaN as no row was tagged True before
2      4  False    1.0  # (4-2)/2
3      7  False    2.5  # (7-2)/2
4     11   True    4.5  # (11-2)/2: 2 is still used as it's 11's last row above tagged as True
5     16  False   0.45  # (16-11)/11
6     22   True    1.0  # (22-11)/11: 11 is still used as it's 22's last row above tagged as True
7     29  False   0.32  # (29-22)/22
8     37   True   0.68  # (37-22)/22: 22 is still used as it's 37's last row above tagged as True
9     46  False   0.24  # (46-37)/37
```

Is there a clean and easy way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we need first create the `groupby` key with `cumsum` , the for each subgroup we need to `shift` the value by group

```
s1=df.tag.iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]
s=df.tag.mul(df.score).groupby(s1).max().shift(-1)
df['rate']=(df.score-s1.map(s))/s1.map(s)
df
Out[75]: 
   score    tag      rate
0      1  False       NaN
1      2   True       NaN
2      4  False  1.000000
3      7  False  2.500000
4     11   True  4.500000
5     16  False  0.454545
6     22   True  1.000000
7     29  False  0.318182
8     37   True  0.681818
9     46  False  0.243243
```

Explain :

Row 9 itself is one group, row 8 - 7 is one group , row 6 to 5 is one group ..., from the tag side , if we reversed the order and do `cumsum`, we can put them into one group, then we need to find the value with tag `True` as the value to shift per group

Comment: Many thanks for this great tip. However I wasn't able to replicate the result using the above solution but had to make the following changes: `s=df.tag.mul(df.score).groupby(s1).max()` and add `x=s1.map(s).shift(2)` then do `df['rate']=(df.score-x)/x`. Is this due to some kind of bug?

Comment: @Rock sorry forget to add shift(-1 ) check the second line

Comment: Thanks very much @BEN_YO for your prompt response. This is greatly helpful!